# Django: Show list of thumbnails in admin change view

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to do something a little bit different than other Django admin thumbnail questions here. I have two models that reference my `Photograph` model either via `ForeignKey` or `ManyToMany` and would like to be able to see the available photos in the admin interface as thumbnails instead of by their title. I've tried using an `admin_thumbnail` method that returns the appropriate HTML as a tag (I've used this elsewhere with success) but to no avail. The list of `Photograph` objects is using their `__unicode__` return value to populate the list, so I tried having `__unicode__` return `mark_safe(the HTML string)` but the list items all end up with empty strings. Any ideas? I'm bad with widgets and I'm hoping a custom widget isn't my only option here.

Comment: Did you set ```admin_thumbnail.allow_tags = True```?

Comment: I thought I'd included this in the original post, but looks like I forgot. Setting `allow_tags` to `True` didn't help. If I don't use `mark_safe` I can see the HTML as a string, but as soon as I use `mark_safe` the text goes completely away. This sounds like an `allow_tags` issue, but I don't know of a way to set `allow_tags` here since I'm using `__unicode__`. Can you set `allow_tags` on `__unicode__`?

Comment: The text should go away if it's html. Did you inspect the source of the web page for the img element?

Comment: Again, you're correct...to be more accurate, there are no elements contained within the `<option>` tags.

Comment: It appears that from the HTML spec `<option>` tags may not have child elements. This is likely the source of the issue. Is there a different built-in widget that would work well for selecting from a list of images?